# How to change background image repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the header banner background image repeatedly in my HTML static page. Right now, it's having only a single bg image. I need to add 2 more images which must change one by one after 4 or 5 secs and repeats the process just like a slider by keeping the content unchanged. Is there any easy method without using slider plugins. Below is my HTML code for the header? Thanks & regards.

```
<header id="home">
    <!-- Background Image -->
    <div class="bg-img" ***style="background-image: url('images/images/p1.png');"***>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Background Image -->

    <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar nav-transparent">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="home">
                        <img class="logo" src="images/logo-png.png" alt="logo" style="width:55%;">
                        <img class="logo-alt" src="images/logo-png.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /Logo -->

                <!-- Collapse nav button -->
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /Collapse nav button -->
            </div>

            <!--  Main navigation  -->
            <ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="what-we-do">What we do</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /Main navigation -->

        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /Nav -->

    <!-- home wrapper -->
    <div class="home-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- home content -->
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="home-content">
                        <h2 class="white-text">uniforms @ competetive rates</h2>
                        <p class="white-text">We are always committed to give you best quality uniform at very competitive rates
                        </p>
                        <a href="aboutus"><button class="white-btn">Read more</button></a>
                        <a href="gallery"><button class="main-btn" style="background-color:#e29d0a">Gallery</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /home content -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /home wrapper -->

</header>
```

Comment: You can do this by selecting element with bg-img class in JS and make simple setInterval function that will change add and remove classes of that element. This means that you will need to have these classes in your css with different urls for background-image properties.

Comment: If you want to achieve the goal, you should write some JS code by vanillaJS or JQuery. Select the element, then use a setInterval to wrap the selector code

Comment: Please add your code into snippet.

Comment: You can do it pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are gonna do this without using slider plugins, that means you have to write your own plugin. Here is a very simple example with using javascript to achieve:

```js
var images = new Array(
  'https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/00ff00/ffffff',
  'https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/0000ff/ffffff',
  'https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/ffff00/ffffff',
  'https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/ff0000/ffffff',
);

var slider = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bg-img')[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("'+images[0]+'")');
  images.splice(images.length, 0, images[0]);
  images.splice(0, 1);
}, 3000);
```

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10% 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/ff0000/ffffff');">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `new Array()` instead of `[]`?

Comment: Hey, it works properly. You saved my time. Thank you.

Comment: Hii, as i said its working properly in desktops. But in mobile only first image is showing. When it changes the first image, then next images are not showing not even the first image. I inspected it in the desktop browser's mobile view. But it is working in browser's mobile view. But not in mobiles. Pls help. Thank you.

Comment: @AMak I've done a testing on mobile and it works properly. (I'm using iPhone). I'm not sure if there are any other factors effect your scripts.

Comment: Hii @Chaska, there is some delay for changing images for the first iteration. After then images are changing smoothly. Is there any tactic to avoid this delay. Thanks & regards.

Comment: Possible to reduce the file size of images?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<div class="bg-img" id="mybg-div">
```

And javascript

```
$(function() {
  var div = $('#mybg-div');
  var backgrounds = ['url(image-one)', 'url(image-two)'];
  var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
 div.css(
   'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
 );

setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  div.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/j20peyfd/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this through keyframe animation:

like

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeBg
        {
            0%   {background-image: url("images/img1.jpg");}
            25%   {background-image: url("images/img2.jpg");}
            50%   {background-image: url("images/img3.jpg");}
            100%   {background-image: url("images/img4.jpg");}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like a plugin:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  const imgOne = 'https://preview.ibb.co/b43uR8/img01.jpg';
  const imgTwo = 'https://preview.ibb.co/ioNAzT/img02.jpg';
  const imgThree = 'https://preview.ibb.co/c9xtKT/img03.jpg';

  const imgArray = [imgOne, imgTwo, imgThree];
  
  $('.bg-img').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArray[0] + ')');
  
  let interval = 0;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    
    if (interval < (imgArray.length - 1)) {
     interval++;
    } else {
     interval = 0;
    }
    
    $('.bg-img').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArray[interval] + ')');
  
  }, 4000);
  
});
```

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, can we add the next prev arrow ? Or progress bar for each image ?